# Sidekiq worker running for thousands of seconds even though there is a timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, semaphore, sidekiq

I have a sidekiq worker that shouldn't take more than 30 seconds, but after a few days I'll find that the entire worker queue stops executing because all of the workers are locked up.

Here is my worker:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Status::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :my_queue, retry: 5, timeout: 4.minutes

  sidekiq_retry_in do |count|
    5
  end

  sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |msg|
    store({message: "Gave up."})
  end

  def perform(id)
    begin
      Timeout::timeout(3.minutes) do
         got_lock = with_semaphore("lock_#{id}") do
           # DO WORK
         end
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      # Handle
    rescue Timeout::Error => e
      # Handle
      raise e
    end
  end

  def with_semaphore(name, &block)
    Semaphore.get(name, {stale_client_timeout: 1.minute}).lock(1, &block)
  end
end
```

And the semaphore class we use.  (redis-semaphore gem)

```
class Semaphore
  def self.get(name, options = {})
    Redis::Semaphore.new(name.to_sym,
      :redis => Application.redis,
      stale_client_timeout: options[:stale_client_timeout] || 1.hour,
    )
  end
end
```

Basically I'll stop the worker and it will state done: 10000 seconds, which the worker should NEVER be running for.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this or what is causing it?  The workers are running on EngineYard.

Edit: One additional comment.  The # DO WORK has a chance to fire off a PostgresSQL function. I have noticed in logs some mention of PG::TRDeadlockDetected: ERROR:  deadlock detected. Would this cause the worker to never complete even with a timeout set?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why are you using a Semaphore Lock inside the worker's "perform" method? I’m asking this because i feel this mix of Sidekiq+Locking is a bit dangerous. [Sidekiq folks recommend](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices) jobs to be as isolated as possible, so there are no bottlenecks or potential deadlocks that may happen by locking stuff during #perform

Comment: In combination with sidetiq I notice that sometimes the same id will be thrown onto the queue to be processed, this prevents it from being processed twice.

Answer (score 1):

Given you want to ensure unique job execution, i would attempt removing all locks and delegate job uniqueness control to a plugin like [Sidekiq Unique Jobs](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs)

In this case, even if sidetiq enqueue the same job id twice, this plugin ensures it will be enqueued/processed a single time.

Comment: So do you believe the issue is redis-semaphore?  I still don't see why timeout would be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem before. To solve this problem, you should stop using Timeout.

As explained in [this article](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting), you should never use Timeout in a Sidekiq job. If you use Timeout, Sidekiq processes and threads can easily break.

Not only Ruby, but also Java has [a similar problem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). Stopping a thread from the outside is inherently dangerous, regardless of the language.

If you continue to have the same problem after deleting Timeout, check that if you are using threads carelessly in your code.

As Sidekiq's architecture is so sophisticated, in almost all cases, the source of the bug is outside of Sidekiq.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the ActiveRecord `with_lock` mechanism: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

Comment: I actually suspect that this may be the real cause of the problem: http://blog.headius.com/2008/02/rubys-threadraise-threadkill-timeoutrb.html

Comment: Ah, yeah, it looks a lot like that. Note to self, don't timeout with a database lock. Is there a reason you need it to time out? Maybe there's a way to break up the logic to allow access to the record in between.

Comment: btw, you should consider answering your own question.